# Given $ X \sim \exp(\lambda) $ find the density function of $Y=\frac{1}{1-X}$

Tags: probability, density-function

> Given $ X \sim \exp(\lambda) $ find the density function of
>   $Y=\frac{1}{1-X}$

So I tried doing the following and gut stuck in the way:

$ F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(\frac{1}{1-x}\leq y)$

Now I though about isolating X, which gives me $ F_x(\text{something}) $ and by deriving it, get the desired density of Y, but I couldn't figure out how to handle the inequality signs (because I can't simply multiple both sides by $1-x$).

What is so wrong with my way of thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Y$ takes values in $(-\infty, 0) \cup [1, \infty)$. It might be helpful to take each case separately.

If $y < 0$, then
$$P(\frac{1}{1-X} \le y) = P(\frac{1}{1-X} \le y, X > 1) = P(1 < X \le 1-\frac{1}{y}).$$

If $y \in [0, 1)$ then $P(\frac{1}{1-X} \le y) = P(\frac{1}{1-X} \le 0) = P(X >  1)$.

If $y \ge 1$, then
$$P(\frac{1}{1-X} \le y) = P(\frac{1}{1-X} \le y, X < 1) + P(X > 1) = P(X \le 1 - \frac{1}{y}) + P(X > 1).$$

Comment: thanks, but could you please clarify your first statement: "please not that Y takes these values" because I am not sure how it works

Comment: @superuser123 Note that $X$ is always nonnegative, and think about what values $\frac{1}{1-X}$ could be. It may help to plot the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: could you please clarify the second case? $y \in [0, 1)$, and in general, could you please explain how you knew how to divide to these cases? thanks!

Comment: @superuser123 Look at a plot of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and figure out where the graph lies below the horizontal line $y = 0.2$ or $y=0.8$ or any $y \in [0, 1)$.